# Eureka Client commons-jxpath Dependency

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

commons-jxpath dependency contains vulnerabilities and currently there is no fix.
However, I wonder what is the use of this library by Eureka Client?
As if I exclude this dependency from eureka client Spring Boot Starter - things continue working just fine - clients are registered in Eureka.
Am I missing anything?

Thank you